# Custom link on facebook's allow access dialog

Tags: facebook, forms-authentication

Some application on facebook, have a custom link (for example to companies' private policy, rules). This link is located in the bottom of Allow access dialog? How can i add such a link to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an application you can give your own Privacy policy , Terms of service , support url from your http://developers.facebook.com/apps page and this page urls are automatically added by facebook to the dialogs/plugins..